# Wordpress "Widgets on Pages" with "Mailchimp Form" - Styling Issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget

First time post so please excuse me if I'm a little rusty. I'm not really a coder but have bodged some code (css) together for my wordpress site at [entirebuyer.com](http://entirebuyer.com)

The issue I am having is that I have set the headings to `Josefin Sans` but the custom CSS I have added for the "Widgets on Pages" plugin is set to `Raleway` and it is buggering up the formatting of the site (especially Headings). Have I missed a `</div>` or something or is the code pants? I also want to know how I can remove that darker border on the email field - make it consistent with the text field. Your help would be much appreciated.

**This is the code, which I have modified from the Wordpress version:**

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mailchimp">
<form action="//entirebuyer.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=5fd2f295964c6123cd956b17a&amp;id=9d81aec625" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<input type="text" size="30" value="Enter Name" name="FNAME" class="name" id="mce-FNAME" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
<input type="email" size="30" value="Enter Email" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_5fd2f295964c6123cd956b17a_9d81aec625" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="mailchimp-button"><input type="submit" value="SEND ME £20" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</div></div>
</form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

**This is the code, which I have added into **CUSTOM CSS** in my theme:**

```
.mailchimp-button{ text-align: center; }

#mailchimp {
background: none;
color: #282828;
padding: 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}


#mailchimp input[type="submit"] {
background: #333333;
font-family: Josefin Sans, Raleway;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;z
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
padding: 10px 10px;
border: none;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}


#mailchimp input[type="submit"]:hover { background: #171717
}

#mailchimp input[type="text"] {
font-family: Josefin Sans, Raleway;
font-size: 16px;color: #8c8989;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px 10px;
width: 200px;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}       

#mailchimp input[type="email"] {
font-family: Josefin Sans, Raleway;
font-size: 16px;
color: #8c8989;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px 10px;
width: 200px;
border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}}
```

**Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a space in your desired font name, you need to wrap it with quotes, like this:

```
#mailchimp input[type="text"] {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', Raleway;
}
```

Without the quotes, browsers try (unsuccessfully) to find fonts named 'Josefin' or 'Sans', and thus fall back to the next correctly-specified font, which in this case was Raleway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin it shouldn't break any style of any widgets.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-to-shortcode/